# List background weird when scroll

Tags: android

I am using list fragment to display items and apply background color to items based on items (Not alternate color). When I scroll the list the background color of list items become weird.

Comment: Try to be more specific, post code and/or screenshots of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your problem truely, following property will help you. Use this property in your list view xml tag.

> android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"

Answer (score 0):

```
list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
list.setCacheColorHint(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```